# Change color of specific glyphicon when clicked using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I would like to change the color of the specific glyphicon clicked in my Angular app.

For example when this is clicked:

```
(in ng-repeat block) <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" ng-click="downvote(post)" ></span>
```

When clicked it calls:

```
$scope.downvote = function(post) {
    posts.downvote(post);   
    }
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a property on the post:

```
$scope.downvote = function(post) {
    posts.downvote(post);
    post.hadDownvote = true;
};
```

Then check the property in an ng-style attribute:

```
<span ng-style="post.hadDownvote ? {color:'red'} : {}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" ng-click="downvote(post)"></span>
```

Naturally, for release you may prefer to use a CSS class defined elsewhere and perform the same check with ng-class to add the class.

Answer (score 0):

you have to drive it via binding so in  ur controller do this but make sure u assing default isDownVote to true or false

```
$scope.downvote = function(post) {
    posts.downvote(post);
   post.isDownVoted = !post.isDownVoted;   
};
```

then in ur html do this

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" ng-click="downvote(post)" ng-class="post.isDownVoted===true ? 'some-color' : ''" ></span>
```

some-color is ur class where you can put ur css.